# How to extract a single type from a Zod union type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I'm using [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) and have an array containing different objects using a [union](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#unions). After parsing it I want to iterate through each item and extract it's "real" type / cut off the other types.

When checking for specific object properties, the following code works fine:

```
const objectWithNumber = zod.object({ num: zod.number() });
const objectWithBoolean = zod.object({ isTruthy: zod.boolean() });
const myArray = zod.array(zod.union([objectWithNumber, objectWithBoolean]));
const parsedArray = myArray.parse([{ isTruthy: true }, { num: 3 }]);

parsedArray.forEach((item) => {
  if ("num" in item) {
    console.info('objectWithNumber:', item);
    // TS knows about it => syntax support for objectWithNumber
  } else if ("isTruthy" in item) {
    console.info('objectWithBoolean:', item);
    // TS knows about it => syntax support for objectWithBoolean
  } else {
    console.error('unknown');
  }
});
```

An alternative would be using [discriminated unions](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#discriminated-unions) for this

```
const objectWithNumber = zod.object({ type: zod.literal("objectWithNumber"), num: zod.number() });
const objectWithBoolean = zod.object({ type: zod.literal("objectWithBoolean"), isTruthy: zod.boolean() });
const myArray = zod.array(zod.discriminatedUnion("type", [ objectWithNumber, objectWithBoolean ]));
const parsedArray = myArray.parse([{ type: "objectWithBoolean", isTruthy: true }, { type: "objectWithNumber", num: 3 }]);

parsedArray.forEach(item => {
  if (item.type === "objectWithNumber") {
    console.info('objectWithNumber:', item);
    // TS knows about it => syntax support for objectWithNumber
  } else if (item.type === "objectWithBoolean") {
    console.info('objectWithBoolean:', item);
    // TS knows about it => syntax support for objectWithBoolean
  } else {
    console.error('unknown');
  }
});
```

but I think I misunderstood this concept because there is just more code to write ( I can always add a shared property and inspect that one ). Any help on this is much appreciated :)

Are there better ways to identify a specific schema?

Comment: Types are only defined at compile time, which means that in order to find out the schema of an 'object', you will need to check its properties.

Comment: You should use a discriminated union for this

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure... I added my solution to the question, do you have any improvements?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your question boils down to "Why one should use discriminated unions instead of shared fields combined with optional fields". (`zod.js` just lifts this concept into runtime providing validation functionality). In your example, there is in fact no reason to use a discriminator (`type` property), because each object holds only a single non-optional property that is mutually exclusive between types and can be easily used to distinguish types. However, the main issue with this code is that the object names (or shapes/structures) **do not communicate any intentions** - that's why it's difficult to see the benefits of discriminated unions.

You can think of discriminated union as a type that **describes** a family of objects and provides an **unified** mechanism (in a form of a discriminator property) to identify them. This approach is less fragile than checking for the existence of some manually picked properties (like for instance `num` property). What if `num` for any reason becomes optional? Then your check for num existence will break.
Another argument for discriminated union is to decrease the number of optional properties. Compare two following examples:

```js
// shared and optional fields instead of discriminated union
type Vehicle = {
  name: string;
  combustionEngine?: PetrolEngine | DieselEngine;
  tankCapacity?: number;
  electricEngine?: ElectricEngine;
  batteryCapacity?: number;
}
```

```js
type Vehicle = 
  | GasolineCar
  | ElectricCar

type = GasolineCar {
  kind: "gasolineCar";
  name: string;
  engine: PetrolEngine | DieselEngine;
  tankCapacity: number;
}

type ElectricCar  = {
  kind: "electricCar"
  name: string;
  engine: ElecticEngine;
  batteryCapacity: number;
}
```

The example with discriminated union produces much more descriptive code. You don't have to add multiple checks for optional fields - instead, just identify (as early as possible) type by discriminator and pass the object to a function/method accepting the more narrow type (`GasolineCar` or `ElectricCar` instead of `Vehicle`).